# How to pass extra argument to the function argument of do.call in R

Tags: r

I'd like to pass argument (`stringsAsFactors=FALSE`) to `rbind` in `do.call`. But the following doesn't work:

```
data <- do.call(rbind, 
          strsplit(readLines("/home/jianfezhang/adoption.txt"), split="\t#\t"), 
          args=list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Comment: rbind has only deparse.level (not stringsAsFactors) argument.

Comment: How about a glimpse at your data? - No sensitive information, please, but a minimal reproducible example (for example, `dput(readLines("/home/jianfezhang/adoption.txt",n=5))`)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(list(iris), list(iris), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

would have been my answer, if it wasn't for the fact that `rbind` does not know what to do with `stringsAsFactors` (but `cbind.data.frame` would).

The output of `strsplit` is presumably a list of vectors, in which case `rbind` creates a matrix. You can specify `stringsAsFactors` when converting this matrix to a data.frame,

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, list(1:10, letters[1:10])), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` globally using `options`:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Setting this at the top of the script will enforce this throughout the script. You could even add to `.Rprofile` to set this option for the all the R sessions you open.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if your function call is valid, but try this:

```
data <- do.call(rbind,
  c(strsplit(readLines("/home/jianfezhang/adoption.txt"),split="\t#\t"),
  list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

You need pass all arguments to `do.call` via one list.
You can concat two list by `c`

```
> c(list(1, 2), list(3, 4))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```